# Defining Python class methods using Cython

Tags: python, cython, pyrex

I am trying to port some Python code to Cython, and it turns out that some of the functionality that I'm trying to port requires class methods (defined using `@classmethod` in the Python code base).

Is it possible to create Python class methods using Cython? If yes, will they follow the same scoping rules that they do in Python? Will I be able to access `cdef` methods that are defined on the instance on the class?

Comment: Pyrex has been obsolete and replaced by Cython for >5 years. Are you actually trying to use it?

Comment: Yes I just realized that. Will modify my question to reflect Cython.

Answer (score 5):

They work fine and behave in basically the same way as Python.

> Will I be able to access cdef methods that are defined on the instance on the class?

I'm not 100% sure what you mean since class methods don't operate on an instance of the class. They can chose to create one if they want, in which case `cdef` methods work fine:

```
cdef class C:
    cdef m(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def c_meth(cls):
        cdef C x = C()
        x.m()
```

The `cdef` method only works because `x` is `cdef`ed to `C` so it knows the type. If you just did

```
    @classmethod
    def c_meth(cls):
        x = C()
        x.m()
```

then you'd get an attribute error (at runtime) since the Cython compiler wouldn't link `x` with the `cdef class C`. This is a general rule and has nothing to do with it being a `classmethod`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clarifies most of my doubts.

To elaborate further, say I have code like this:
```
class A():
  cdef foo(self):
    pass

  @classmethod
  def bar(cls):
    foo()
```

Since `foo` is defined on the instance of `A` is it possible to access `foo` from `bar` (which is a class method)?

Comment: No. But it isn't in Python either. `foo` requires an instance of `A` and `bar` only has an object representing the class `A`. You should try this code out in Python and inspect the types of `cls` and `self` to work out what's happening.